# Risco em permitir que os desenvolvedores upem arquivos .blade

Tags: php, laravel, segurança, framework, laravel-blade

Estou desenvolvendo uma plataforma de blog em que os usuários enviam seu template e o Laravel usa esse template para construir o blog. O usuário/desenvolvedor só vai informar onde ficarão os valores, exemplo:

```
<h2>{{$blog->title}}</h2>
```

Posso permitir que um desenvolvedor/usuário faça um template usando as chaves ( {{ e }} ) do blade sem que isso afete a segurança?

Comment: Poder pode, só vai precisar limitar o que será usado. Como disse o @Neto, haverá esse risco se você permitir o uso das classes e propriedades do Laravel.

Answer (score 13):

```
{{var_dump(Config::get('database'))}}
```

E já era...

Comment: acho que com essa não precisa se dizer mais nada néh?

Comment: Essa foi a melhor resposta que eu vi nas últimas semanas! +1

Answer (score 3):

Além do risco já citado acima, existem outros inúmeros.

Quando você usa `$this` dentro de uma view `blade`, você tem acesso a instância de `Illuminate\View\View`.

Sem contrar outros métodos que ele poderia brincar a vontade com seu sistema.

Só para reforçar a resposta acima, veja outro "sacanagem" que poderia acontecer:

```
File::deleteDirectory('diretorio_importante_do_seu_sistema');
```

Poderia também alterar algum arquivo de configuração, como o `mail.php` e fazer uma arruaça no seu sistema:

```
 file_put_contents(app_path('config/mail.php'), var_export($configuracoes_malicosas, true));
```

Talvez a solução no seu caso seja fazer um pré-processamento de um possível template enviado por um usuário. Ou ainda, ter um bloqueio, para alguém analisar o conteúdo dessa view e, só então, publicar efetivamente.

Não sei se a ideia é essa, mas parece que você deseja fazer algo semelhante ao Wordpress.

O Laravel já tem um CMS, não sei se resolve, mas vou deixar o link para que você possa analisar e ver se atende a sua  necessidade.

https://octobercms.com/